# Latest Sofia-Sip responds automatically with 200 to incoming INFO

Tags: sip, sofia-sip

i am using the sofia-sip library (an open source, cross-platform  SIP stack) and what i see is that it responds automatically to incoming SIP INFO even tho' the INFO messages belong to a SIP dialog that has already been destroyed... has anyone experienced the same issue?
Previous version of the library did not seem to show this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about any change in behaviour in Sofia-SIP between releases.

If you want to control SIP method handling in your application, rather than letting Sofia-SIP automatically respond to it, then at initialisation you should call `nua_set_params()` and pass it [`NUTAG_APPL_METHOD("<METHOD-NAME>")`](http://sofia-sip.sourceforge.net/refdocs/nua/nua__tag_8h.html#aa556061c2b7306080669012a49e1aca0), e.g. `NUTAG_APPL_METHOD("INFO")`.

If you have further questions, you may want to ask on the [Sofia-SIP mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/sofia-sip-devel).

Comment: i need to create and application with sofia , and i know nothing about sip and sofia , can you please guide me !

Comment: @DevangGoswami: You want me to write a SIP and Sofia-SIP tutorial for you? Sorry, I haven't really got the time and resources for that. For SIP, I suggest you read the SIP RFCs, starting with [RFC 3261](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3261). For Sofia-SIP, I suggest you look at the example application, and adapt it to your needs.